# LoadRunner Referer option, what is it used for?

Tags: loadrunner

Why is "Referer=myurl.com" appear within a web_submit_data() or web_url() function?

Is this some kind of base-url thing to tell LoadRunner where you are standing when i.e. saying:

web_url("something",
"URL=iamgoingtothisurl",

What is the purpose of this "Referer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referer element is not something defined by HP, Mercury or in LoadRunner itself, but it is defined by the relevant RFCs for HTTP and HTML,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer